# Por que no C++ existe o endl, sendo que o \n já executa o mesmo procedimento?

Tags: c++

Peço desculpas se a pergunta parecer trivial, mas não entendi o porquê de ser criado o endl no C++, sendo que o \n já executa a mesma tarefa. Não seria "reinventar a roda"?

Comment: Pq "\n" é a quebra de linha qdo a sua stream de saída é `std::cout`, mas qdo a stream de saída é de um arquivo, "\n" pode ser incompatível. Por isso criaram `std::endl`, para ter uma interface unificada.

Answer (score 6):

```
std::endl;
```

força um `flush` na saída. `cout` não é a única saída possível para *streams* e em muitos casos pode ser importante garantir o `flush()` na mesma hora para ter certeza de que os dados foram gravados ou transmitidos antes de continuar. Pode ser um painel de LED por exemplo e um `endl;` vai provavelmente instruir o driver para mostrar a mensagem na mesma hora. Um `"\n"` pode só colocar os dados lá e ficar aguardando o `flush()`. O painel pode ser multi-linhas por exemplo. Ou pode ser um buffer de transmissão aguardando sinal pra transmitir uma mensagem que pode ter muitos `"\n"`.
E `endl;` é mais fácil de digitar :)

Mas no caso de `cout` e `cerr` é desnecessário e pode sair caro em termos de performance. Mas isso tem provavelmente zero importância porque programas que escrevem em `cout` são por definição muito muito lentos: grande chance de serem programas interativos. Note que programas em C++ em geral não escrevem em `cout` ou `cerr` afinal, exceto por testes e programas de estudantes. E `cerr` é a *stream* padrão de erro então a performance é pouco importante, afinal já deu erro mesmo. Programas em C++ geralmente falam com outros programas e estruturas complexas.

De todo modo está na bíblia das [recomendações de uso](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-lambda-init), **C++ Core Guidelines**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
A sugestão é para evitar e a conclusão lá é de que no fundo é *raramente* importante e acaba sendo uma escolha estética. E na hora de digitar `"` em geral precisa de `shift` e `'\'` pode estar em lugares estranhos do teclado, enquanto `endl;` está em posição muito mais favorável. Nos teclados ocidentais `endl;` é muito mais rápido :) No teclado internacional `l` e `;` são adjacentes e em todo teclado qwerty `e` e `d` ficam lado a lado por exemplo... E por exemplo no ABNT aspas e backslash ficam nos extremos do teclado. Um p0$$E afinal.

Answer (score 2):

o `\n` só ocupa um espaço na string pra pular a linha
já o `endl` é um objeto que executa um `\n`, mas também faz um `flush` no `buffer` `stdout`

o `endl` é uma melhor pratica no código, pois limpa o `buffer` junto, mas ele usa mais processamento que o `\n`

Answer (score 2):

A diferença entre ambos é o fato de que std::endl força o uso std::flush na operação de saída, mas poderá comprometer o desempenho.

Diferença explícita:

```
std::cout << "\n" << std::flush
```

&

```
std::cout << std::endl
```